# Picasso Image library - Lower quality whilst maintaining aspect ratio and image dimensions

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using the [Picasso image library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) but seem to be missing one feature. I want to be able to display images maintaining the original aspect ratio but reducing the quality enough so the Bitmap in memory is small enough to be manageable.

I see the `fit()` and `resize()` methods; however, I don't think either of these are appropriate as I load images into a custom ImageView which scales to the dimensions of the image (with a max width). - `fit()` is useless as the custom ImageView needs to resize to the Image not the other way around.

What I need is a way to specify the inSampleSize used or, even better, a max width to load the image at which respects the aspect ratio.

Is there a way to do this other than changing the source myself?

Comment: I've had the same issue with Picasso. I've switched to Glide which almost has a very similar API (uses Volley though). The only different is that Glide allows you to plug in your own DownSampler. You'll need to create both a DownSampler and Transformation to achieve what you need.

Comment: Picasso offers a `RequestHandler` in 2.4.0 for full control of decoding the bitmaps.

Comment: I struggled where you are, however, resize(imgae_width,image_height) solved the problem.